# about a geometry problem

Tags: geometry

Let $M$ be the middle of the segment $[BC]$ and $P$ the middle of the segment $[BM]$. A point $A$ in the exterior of the segment $[BC]$ such that $\angle BAP=\angle PAM=\angle MAC$. Find the measure of the following angles: $\angle BAC, \angle CBA, \angle BCA$?

Can you find the measure of the angles without using Pythagora's theorem?

Comment: Does such point $A$ with those hypothesis exist? How to prove this?

Comment: Don't know about whether Pythagorean Theorem is necessary. I certainly used it in solving the problem.  Also used somewhat fancier tools.

Comment: Yes, can avoid using Pythagoreaan Theorem directly. Don't know about indirectly.

Comment: please, can you write a solution:) thanks

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how did you prove that $A$ exists?

Comment: @Sigur: Well, I didn't really worry about it, since it was geometrically clear. But an easy formal proof is by exhibiting a triangle $ABC$ that works.

Comment: It is clear that $\triangle ABM$ should be isosceles. So $A$ should be on the mediatrix of $BM$. Then, for each point $A$ we have the angle $\theta=\angle BAP$. So we have to construct over $MC$ the arc for this angle and guarantee its intersection with the mediatrix.

Comment: @Sigur: just take half of an equilateral triangle. Picture can be found below in my answer.

Comment: Dear @Iuli, I think it would be nice if next time you give a meaningful title to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Denote $BAC$ by $3\alpha$, $CBA$ by $\beta$, $ACB$ by $\gamma$.

I'm not sure if it qualifies, but you can see that from the fact that the angular bisector divides the third side of a triangle in proportion equal to the proportion of the two other sides ([angle bisector theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)), so the triangle $AMB$ must be isosceles, by applying it to the triangle $PAC$ you see that the cosine of $2\alpha$ is $\frac {1}{2}$.

So $2\alpha=\pi/3$, $\beta=\pi/2-\alpha=\pi/3$, $\gamma=\pi-\beta-3\alpha=\pi/6$

Comment: Very nice. how did you draw this ?

Comment: @Belgi: [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/). It's a good tool to cheat with to solve high school geometry problems. ;-)

Comment: Why $\cos(2\alpha)=1/2$? We know that it is $AP/AC$.

Comment: @Sigur: by angular bisector theorem. Notice that $MC$ is twice as long as $PM$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=\angle BAP$. 
At least one of the triangles $BPA$, $PMA$ has an angle $\ge\frac\pi2$ at $P$ (and a nonzero angle at $B$ or $M$, respectively). From the sum of angles in a triangle, we conclude $\alpha<\frac\pi2$.
Construct $X$ such that $\angle PBX=\frac\pi2-\alpha$ and $XP\perp BC$.
Then $\angle BXP=\alpha$ and $A,X$ are on the same side of $BC$. Therefore by the inverse of the inscribed angle theorem, $A$ is on the circumscribed circle of $BPX$.
Reflecting the figure at $BP$, we find $\angle PXM=\alpha$, hence $A$ is also on the circumscribed circle of $PMX$. These two circles intersect exactly in $P$ and $X$. From $A\ne P$ we conclude $A=X$ and from this $|AB|=|AM|$

Translate the figure by $\overrightarrow{BM}$. Then $B\mapsto M$, $M\mapsto C$, $A\mapsto A''$. Since $|A''M|=|A''C|$, let $c$ be the circle araound $A''$ through $M$ and $C$. Because $\angle MA''C=2\alpha$, the circle $c$ is the locus of all points $X$ with $\angle MXC=\alpha$. Hence $A\in c$.
We conclude that $|BM|=|AA''|=|A''M|=|AB|$, i.e. $BMA$ is equilateral, hence $\alpha=\frac\pi6$. 
The rest is easy: $\angle BAC=3\alpha=\frac\pi2$, $\angle CBA=\frac\pi2-\alpha=\frac\pi3$, $\angle BCA=\frac\pi2-2\alpha=\frac\pi6$.

Answer (score 0):

My friend with I work a lot gave me a very interesting solution. For the beginning I will introduce the draw.
[image]

Notations:
$$BP=x.$$

Because $BP=x$ it follows that $PM=x$ and $MC=2x.$ $M \in[AM)$ and $[AM)$ is bisector of the angle $\angle PAC$ $\Rightarrow$ $MQ \perp AC$ and $MQ=PM$, so $MQ=x.$ So knowing that the triangle $\triangle MQC$ is a rectangular angle and $MC=2MQ$ $\Rightarrow$ the measure of the angle $\angle C=30^{\circ}$. What it remained to prove is easy to demonstrate it. ($\triangle ABM$ is isosceles because $P$ is a middle of $BM$ and $\angle BAP=\angle PAM$ from here the measure of the angle $\angle APM =90^{\circ}$).